# How to get yearWeek in python like we get using DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear() in C#?

Tags: c#, python

I want to get yearWeek in python from datetime. I have used IsoCalender()[1] but it returns different week then I get in C# using DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(Date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday).

```
I have tried:

1) IsoCalender()[1].

2) d = datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-09-22 00:00:00.00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
print(datetime.datetime.strftime(d,'%W'))

So For '2017-09-22 00:00:00.00' In C# I get 39 but I get 38 in python using above mentioned techniques.
```

Any help will be highly appretiated.

Comment: Did you try `datetime.date(2010, 6, 16).strftime("%V")` ?

Comment: I tried it just now, but still it returns 38 for "2017-09-22 00:00:00.00" but in C# using  DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(Date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday) it returns 39. please help, I am into this for 3 hours.

Comment: what do you get in C# ? (I see above 39).

Comment: string date = "2017-09-22 00:00:00.000";
DateTime dateTimez = Convert.ToDateTime(date);

int week = DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dateTimez , CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday)

Comment: @balderman. Is this difference due to different implementations in these languages?

Comment: .I am not sure why there is a difference ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ISO 8601 (cf. [this draft von 2016, section 5.7.7](https://www.loc.gov/standards/datetime/iso-tc154-wg5_n0039_iso_wd_8601-2_2016-02-16.pdf))

> A week is defined as a seven-day time interval, starting with a Monday. *Week number one of the calendar year is the first week that contains at least four (4) days in that calendar year.*

The documentation of Python's [date.isocalendar](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar) states likewise:

> […] week starts on a Monday and ends on a Sunday. *The first week of an ISO year is the first (Gregorian) calendar week of a year containing a Thursday.*

According to the [documentation of CalendarWeekRule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.calendarweekrule?view=netframework-4.7.2]) this equals **`CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek`**:

> Indicates that the first week of the year is the first week with four or more days before the designated first day of the week.

Whereas `CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay` means:

> Indicates that the first week of the year starts on the first day of the year and ends before the following designated first day of the week.

In conclusion, the correct way in C# is:

```
DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(new DateTime(2017, 9, 22), CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday)
```

which correctly yields 38.